# Variable return type in objective-c function (with Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, return-type

I have a configuration class in my objective-c app which reads a PLIST file with configuration data. I would then like to be able to read the value for any key with a single function, something like this:

```
- () getValueforKey:(NSString *)key {
     some magic here....
     return value;
}
```

The issue: Some of the values in the config file are Strings, others are ints or even Dictionaries. As you can see I left the return-type blank in this example as I do not know what to write there. Is there any way that a function can return different types of data, and if so, how do I declare this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safest is to provide a distinct method for each type you support:

```
- (NSString *)stringForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (int)intForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (float)floatForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForKey:(NSString *)key;
...
```

You could supply a generic one in case the caller wants to work generically:

```
- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)key;
```

In this case you would return `NSString *`, `NSNumber *`, `NSDictionary *`, etc.

Comment: I was thinking about the first one too, yet I prefer a single function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you find yourself writing lots of `isKindOfClass:` based conditional code, it generally indicates that your code is not following patterns consistent with the frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

make use of Objective-C's dynamic typing with **id**

```
- (id) getValueforKey:(NSString *)key {
     some magic here....
     return value;
}
```

Comment: Won't work for `int`, `float` and other non-object data types.